Selenium Wire: Connect to an Existing Firefox Marionette Session (Python)
I can't figure out how to connect to an existing Firefox marionette session using Selenium Wire.
I can connect to an existing marionette session using Selenium:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
service = webdriver.FirefoxService(service_args = ['--marionette-port', '2828', '--connect-existing'] )
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options= options,service=service)

But when I use the same FirefoxOptions in Selenium Wire, it opens a new Firefox session without connecting to the existing Marionette session:
seleniumwire_options = {
    'service_args': {'--marionette-port', '2828', '--connect-existing'},
}

driver = seleniumwire_webdriver.Firefox(
    options=fireFoxOptions,
    seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options )

When I try to "combine" them using this:
service = seleniumwire_webdriver.FirefoxService(service_args = ['--marionette-port', '2828', '--connect-existing'] )
driver = seleniumwire_webdriver.Firefox(options= options,service=service)

I get an error:
module 'seleniumwire.webdriver' has no attribute 'FirefoxService'

My question: How do I use Selenium Wire to connect to an existing Firefox Marionette session, so that it doesn't open a new browser session?
